# JaCoCo report sort controls inactive in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Our build uses Maven to generate an aggregate JaCoCo report.  When Jenkins builds our project and publishes the report, the sort controls in the column headers do not work when the report is viewed inside Jenkins.

Is there a way to make these controls work?

[image: Jacoco Report in Jenkins with inactive controls circled]

These controls work when a developer builds on his workstation.  They also work if you click "Zip" at the top of the Jenkins page, and download and unpack the report web pages and view the local copies.  They only seem to not work when viewed from the link Jenkins provides on the job's build page.

In Jenkins, the configuration to publish the report is from a post-build step "Publish HTML report".  The entire jacoco report folder is copied with root page "index.html".  All three "advanced" options are checked (keep past reports, link to last build, allow missing reports) and we copy everything (**/*)  Jenkins is 2.121 running on Windows Server 2012.  Report generated by Maven 3.5.3 and Jacoco maven plugin 0.8.1.  Browsers tried - MSIE 11, Google Chrome 66.0.

[image: Jenkins report publish configuration]

Comment: These controls in JaCoCo report use JavaScript, so maybe relates to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32026?focusedCommentId=244023#comment-244023 ?

Comment: Seems plausible.  After viewing that page and its links, I tried tweaking security settings, but to no avail.  Interestingly, I discovered that the controls worked in the child JaCoCo pages (i.e., specific package pages), even with the default security settings.  Only the main page seems to be disabled.